# Remove Site URL Showing Before Email Link

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I feel like this is a rookie question, but for some reason I can't figure this out.

How do I remove our site URL from appearing before the email?

```
echo '<a href="'.$business_email.'">Email</a>';
```

Renders...

http://www.oursite.com/test@test.com

The email address itself is inputted in WordPress admin custom field if that makes a difference.

Comment: If you put mailto: in front of it? So `echo '<a href="mailto:'.$business_email.'">Email</a>';`

Comment: add the mailto:

Comment: Thanks, I tried mailto already, but I must've entered it wrong in a frenzy of anger. Haha. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get the link to send an email you should change your code to this:

```
echo '<a href="mailto:'.$business_email.'">Email</a>';
```

It may be that when you click the link it is just appending the email to your site's URL.

If you are, in fact, getting that string directly from the database, you can try removing your website using the `str_replace()` function:

```
$baseurl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$business_email = str_replace( $baseurl, $business_email, '' );

echo '<a href="mailto:'.$business_email.'">Email</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks Mathew. As I stated above.... I tried mailto already, but I must've entered it wrong in a frenzy of anger. Haha. It works now.